# PUT in JMeter 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm new in Performance Tests, I started using JMeter and creating my own scripts. I am doing stress performance test on an API, until now POST, GET, PATCH all were working, but I stopped at PUT method. I need to send a file using PUT method, in POSTMAN is working (in body I am using file type with the selected file, in the header multipart/form-data).

I tried to put the file path in "Send files with the request", Parameter Name: file, MIME type: form-data, Content encoding: utf-8.

In the request it doesn't give me the file.

> PUT http://10.111.30.12/api/tasks/2
>
> PUT data:
>
> [no cookies]
>
> Request Headers:
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> X-AuthToken:
>   MjEzNUZFMEMxMzFEQTVBMUMxQzYxMDU0MjE0OEFFRTJDRjU0ODQ0QkRCNDUyQkQ0QTgxREU0M0Y5MDQwMTk1RDJGMEE2RDNERTIxNjFBRjE3MEQ0QTNFQzM1OTVBRjMyQUI0MkJFN0MwMjYxMkFDRTBFMTQyMzYyNjYwMkREMTU0RkMxQTlBMjJDOUJFQkMwRjEwNDdFOTEwNjgyRDAwMTVBOTlEQ0ExQ0FFQTBGQjA2MEVDRUNFQjgzOEQ1MTA4ODVGOUYxMDhBQUM0RTc5N0JDQTA2RkYyNjYxQURGODE3NUM0MDlFN0RENEM0MTc0Nzc4MzczRjNDQ0VDQzM3Q0Y2QzU4REE2ODg2QzAyNEE1MzY0QThDN0IwMjhEMjdE
>
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Host: 10.111.30.12
>
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)"
>
> The sampler result:
>
> Thread Name: API Thread Group 1-1
>
> Sample Start: 2015-09-21 15:33:53 EEST
>
> Load time: 22
>
> Connect Time: 0
>
> Latency: 22
>
> Size in bytes: 202
>
> Headers size in bytes: 202
>
> Body size in bytes: 0
>
> Sample Count: 1
>
> Error Count: 1
>
> Response code: 415
>
> Response message: Unsupported Media Type

Also tried to put the file in body data as: "file: C:\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\API Performance Test\file.txt" but now I am getting 400 bad request.

Please if anyone got any idea on how to do this, tell me too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're testing an API my expectation is that you need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`.

The best way to get to the bottom of the issue is using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to compare what's being sent by Postman and JMeter and make sure that there are no differences.

Comment: I am using Fiddler, but it doesn't read the proper way multipart/form-data type. I will try Wireshark maybe I will get something.